# How can I report the results of a two-way ANOVA on a 3x4 factorial experiment?

Tags: r, anova, reporting, effects

I'm trying to generate some sort of table that shows statistical differences between my X1 and X2 variables, using a 2-way ANOVA test.

I have a fertilizer experiment where I'm looking at the effect of four different fertilizer rates (0x, 1x, 4x, and 8x label rates) on three different cultivars of plants (pio, tol, sus). The experiment was a randomized-complete-block design, with a 3x4 factorial experimental arrangement. Each treatment was replicated three times.

I was interested in seeing how aerial imaging scores (Y) compared with fertilizer rate (X1) and cultivar type (X2). I did this, and generated a boxplot to show the differences among treatments, on a given day of observation.

Since I'm running the analysis in R, the code would look like this:
`mod1 <- lm(Score ~ rate + cultivar, data = dataframe)`

I fitted the ANOVA model...

```
library(car)
Anova(mod1)
```

...and obtained the below results:

```
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: SR
          Sum Sq Df F value  Pr(>F)    
rate       31.01  3   30.90 2.6e-09 ***
cultivar    4.42  2    6.61  0.0042 ** 
Residuals  10.04 30
```

I also checked for an interaction effect, and there was no significant interaction. Therefore, after checking the assumptions, I used the `lsmeans` package to check for significant interactions between the groups:

```
#Checking to see if the CULTIVARS have a significant interaction on the scores:

lsmeans(mod1, pairwise~cultivar)

###Results of the above code:

$lsmeans
 cultivar lsmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 pio         4.2 0.167 30      3.9      4.5
 sus         3.4 0.167 30      3.1      3.7
 tol         4.1 0.167 30      3.8      4.4

Results are averaged over the levels of: rate 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast  estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 pio - sus     0.79 0.236 30  3.300  0.0100 
 pio - tol     0.10 0.236 30  0.400  0.9100 
 sus - tol    -0.69 0.236 30 -2.900  0.0200
```

```
#Checking to see if the RATES have a significant interaction on the scores:
lsmeans(mod1, pairwise~rate)

###Results of the above code:

$lsmeans
 rate lsmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 0X      5.1 0.193 30      4.7      5.5
 1X      4.5 0.193 30      4.1      4.8
 4X      3.4 0.193 30      3.0      3.7
 8X      2.7 0.193 30      2.3      3.1

Results are averaged over the levels of: cultivar 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 0X - 1X      0.64 0.273 30 2.400   0.1080 
 0X - 4X      1.74 0.273 30 6.400   <.0001 
 0X - 8X      2.38 0.273 30 8.700   <.0001 
 1X - 4X      1.10 0.273 30 4.000   0.0020 
 1X - 8X      1.74 0.273 30 6.400   <.0001 
 4X - 8X      0.65 0.273 30 2.400   0.1050
```

I'm trying to generate some type of table that shows the results of the ab ove tests. How can I report the results of these tests? Based on the results from the data above, there are some differences between cultivars and rates. How can I demonstrate these relationships in a table?

Edit: As requested, here is the result of the code `plot(allEffects(mod1))`:

[image]

Comment: Going into this experiment, were you interested in any *a priori* specific comparisons? Also, can you show here the plot that you would obtain with the commands: **library(effects); plot(allEffects(model))** where model is your lm() model which allows for an interaction between rate and cultivar.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I have updated the question with the ```effects``` code. What is this telling me? I'm not a statistics expert.